# Accessing Gmail SMTP via Python - AUTH issues

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm writing this currently for an assignment but years back I had the same problem and just gave up. Further searches had me try a variety of things and I cannot get past the login portion.

```
from socket import *
from ssl import *


msg = "\r\n I love computer networks!"
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
mailserver = getaddrinfo('smtp.gmail.com',465, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)[0][4]
clientSocket = wrap_socket(clientSocket)

clientSocket.connect(mailserver)

recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print '220 reply not received from server.'

clientSocket.send('EHLO Nolan\r\n')
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

clientSocket.send('AUTH LOGIN ' + 'my Google email'.encode('base64','strict'))
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv
print recv.split()[1].decode('base64')

clientSocket.send("my password".encode('base64','strict'))
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv

# And onto other tasks
```

I'm under the impression I don't need `STARTTLS` as I start the connection with SSL. If I change `AUTH LOGIN` to `AUTH PLAIN` it doesn't know how to decode it. If I use `PLAIN` but don't encode it my program just hangs. If I terminate it with "\n\r" (not encoded) I get a broken pipe. Using the code above I get the password request.

Then sending the password I get `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not excepted.`It's the same password I sign in with?!? I already setup my account to allow less secure devices. 2-step verification... started the process seems to be orientated to mobile phones, not my python app.

I've changed `EHLO` to use my IP, as I believe RFC 5321 says that's how it should be. Didn't matter.

I've looked through RFC 4954...

I dug into `smtplib` to uncover `"AUTH PLAIN " + encode_base64("\0%s\0%s" % (user,pass),eol='')` Just hangs... waiting...

I have no clue.

**Update**

I changed the `smtplib` to output every string submitted. This confuses me even more:

```
ehlo [127.0.1.1]

AUTH PLAIN [almost forgot one can decode this base64]==

mail FROM:<[gmail account]>

rcpt TO:<[hotmail account]>

data

quit
```

My `AUTH` string is exactly the same but it hangs. And I am receiving the email at my hotmail account (using smtplib, not my code).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic, non-SSL connection to Gmail, you can use this:

```
import smtplib
gmail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
gmail.ehlo() #open the connection
gmail.starttls()
gmail.login("gmaillogin","gmailpassword") #login*
gmail.quit() #close the connection
```

*Note: You will need to generate a gmail application password from your google account.

**Edit:**
If you want to use SSL encryption, use this (thanks to furas):

```
import smtplib
gmail = smtp.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",465)
gmail.ehlo()
gmail.login("gmaillogin","gmailpassword")
gmail.quit()
```

Comment: for SSL you need `SMTP_SSL()`, port `465`, and without `starttls()`

Comment: @furas Well there ya go. Thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks. :) Unfort I can't use it as I'm circumventing the assignment by using a library purposed to the task... But it works (silently exits so I assume so), which just means I failed and must revisit the library and figure out what I'm not doing.

Answer (score 0):

As is typically my fashion, it's the simple things. I just spent hours looking over one program and Googling only to have one error pop out at me: the parameter order in my definition was not how I used it in my code.

Here... I changed my code to use `AUTH PLAIN` and the issue... I had been putting in `'\n\r'` not `'\r\n'` (if I had ended the command with anything, only omitted because `'\n\r'` produced errors on some commands and went through okay on others). Thank you for classical music to study by on your favorite streaming video site. It raised my intelligence briefly. :)

```
clientSocket.send('AUTH PLAIN ' + encode_base64("\0%s\0%s" % ([email],[password]), eol="") + '\r\n')
```